# Ho do I intercept wiremock request to replace its entire body with new body

Tags: java, encryption, stub, wiremock

I am getting wiremock request which is in encrypted format (either whole body or some fields). I wanted to create a wiremock extension which intercepts wiremock request and replaces encrypted body with decrypted body content (received by calling http post request for decryption). This helps me to create a generic solution to decrypt all incoming wiremcok requests so that matchers can work on decrypted data.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

To achieve this, implement a subclass of `StubRequestFilter` and register it as an extension.

Your class's `filter(...)` method will need to wrap the request in a `RequestWrapper` that transforms the body by calling `transformBody(...)` with a function that decrypts the data.

You can find some examples of this here: https://github.com/wiremock/wiremock/blob/master/src/test/java/com/github/tomakehurst/wiremock/RequestFilterAcceptanceTest.java